Not able to open the disk image of ubuntu
I downloaded the ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and then created a disk image on a Sandisk Cruzer blade 64gb pendrive using balenaEtcher on a mac. Now i want to boot into ubuntu using the pendrive on the mac. I turned off the mac and clicked the option key while it was turning on and it opens the startup disk manager. In it the connected drive is shown as a efi drive and it should ideally boot into ubuntu but whenever i click on it, it starts booting into macos and then a error message shows the macos version needs to be recovered in the selected drive and donot boot into ubuntu. Can someone please solve this issue.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
